# Sending field parameters to SSRS action link

Tags: reporting-services

I was trying to pass field parameters to Action Link in SSRS like,
 http://mysite.aspx?id="+Fields!ID.Value

but it is saying as, Input String was not in a correct format. When i tried with the format
as http://mysite.aspx?id=10(10 is static not dynamic). It is not showing any error.

Please tell me what i can do, as i'm struck up with this issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Raghava.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

right click the field you want to make hyperlink and select `TextBox Properties`, and then go to `Action` tab in the popup that appears.

and choose `Go To Url` option and click on expression and set the below given expression.

```
="http://mysite.aspx?id=" & Fields!ID.Value
```

it should work.

[image]

Comment: Hi Manish,Thanks for answer. What if i have to pass multiple parameters. Like id=Fields!ID.Value&Name=Fileds!Name.Value

Comment: `="http://mysite.aspx?id=" & Fields!Id.Value & "&Name=" & Fields!Name.Value`.  this is your expression.

Comment: notice, the fragments inside double quote. you are basically concatenating multiple strings.

Comment: Guys, when I use the format describe above, the field is no longer a link. Any ideas why?