# SSRS: Sending field parameters from SSRS action link not working

Tags: reporting-services

I followed steps mentioned here- [SSRS: How to display a hyperlink in sql services reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878752/ssrs-how-to-display-a-hyperlink-in-sql-services-reporting)

And also tried this but not working parameter is always null.

[Sending field parameters to SSRS action link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682158/sending-field-parameters-to-ssrs-action-link)

*My Parameter is a Guid*

How to add a parameter like this - https://stackoverflow.com/78450

My url which i get in my report is like this - http://mysite.aspx?id=